# Stop Software center from asking me to log in Ubuntu One

Tags: 13.10, ubuntu-one, software-center

Since I upgraded to 13.10, every time I open Software center, I'm asked to login to Ubuntu One.

I don't have an account and am not interested in opening one.

Is it possible to stop Software center from asking me to login Ubuntu One?

Answer (score 1):

If you have ever logged into Software Center in a previoius version of Ubuntu, purchased any apps or music, or logged into Launchpad, or some other services, then you already have an Ubuntu One account. Ubuntu One is the single-sign-on service for Ubuntu, as well as providing other services such as file sync and music streaming, if you choose to use those services. You are not required to use the additional services if you don't want to use them.

However, in order to purchase any apps, or access the previously purchased app features of Software Center, you will need to log in to the Ubuntu One service. The e-mail address and password will be the same one you use to log in to Launchpad or which you have used in the past for Software Center, though.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I never bought software and even though I do have a launchpad account I don't want to associate it with Software center. In previous editions I was never asked to login and everything works when I simply close the login window.